# custom post types shortode stays on top of other page contents. Is there a bug?

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I have created a custom portfolio post type for my wordpress theme, and I have made a shortcode for it too. But when I create a page and use the shortcode to display limited number of my portfolio items, no matter where in the page I insert my shortcode, the portfolio items always stay on top of other contents, I took a look at the source code of the page and for no reason this shortcode is process before any other code is processed on the page.

I even tested it on a post, when the post is viewed on the main blog archive page, the shortcode is processed where I want it to be, but when the article is being viewed as a single article again the shortcode is processed and displayed on top of all the contents of that article or page.

here is the code I used for the shortcode:

```
    add_shortcode( 'portfolios', 'ub_portfolios_sc' );
    function ub_portfolios_sc ( $atts ) {
    global $post;
    $default = array(
        'type'         => 'post',
        'post_type'    => 'portfolios',
        'limit'        => 12,
        'order'        => 'ASC',
        'orderby'      => 'date',
        'status'       => 'publish',
        'post_columns' => 'three'
    );
    $r = shortcode_atts( $default, $atts );
    extract( $r );

    if( empty($post_type) )
    $post_type = $type;

    $post_type_ob = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
    if( !$post_type_ob )
    return '<div class="warning"><p>No such post type <em>' . $post_type . '</em> found.</p></div>';

    $args = array(
        'post_type'    => $post_type,
        'numberposts'  => $limit,
        'post_status'  => $status,
        'post_columns' => $post_columns,
        'order'        => $order,
        'orderby'      => $orderby
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    if( count($posts) ):
        echo '<ul id="portfolio-grid" class="portfolio-grid unstyled '.$post_columns.'-cols">';
        foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-largesrc="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo ub_featured_img_url('portfolio-fullsize'); } else { ?>http://placehold.it/600&text=<?php _e('No Thumbnails', 'une_boutique'); } ?>" data-title="<?php the_title() ?>" data-button="<?php _e('View Project', 'une_boutique'); ?>" data-description="<?php the_excerpt() ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else { ?>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320&text=<?php _e('No Thumbnails', 'une_boutique'); ?>" alt="no thumbnails">
                <?php } ?>
            <span class="item-title"><span class="arrow-shape-up"></span><?php the_title() ?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
        endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</ul>';
    endif;
}
```

and here is how I created the custom post type in the first place:

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register', 0);

function portfolio_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Portfolios', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/sofa.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt'),
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'portfolios' , $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();

set_post_thumbnail_size( 600, 600, true );
}

register_taxonomy("Categories",
array("portfolios"),
    array(
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "label" => __('Categories', 'une_boutique'),
        "singular_label" => __('Category', 'une_boutique'),
        "rewrite" => true
    )
);

add_action("admin_init", "admin_init", 10);

function admin_init(){
add_meta_box("project_date-meta", __('Project Date', 'une_boutique'), "project_date", "portfolios", "side", "low");
add_meta_box("project_client-meta", __('Project Client', 'une_boutique'), "project_client", "portfolios", "side", "low");
add_meta_box("project_link-meta", __('Project Link', 'une_boutique'), "project_link", "portfolios", "side", "low");
}

function project_date(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$project_date = $custom["project_date"][0];
?>
<label for="project-date"><?php __('Year:', 'une_boutique') ?></label><br />
<input id="project-date" name="project_date" value="<?php echo $project_date; ?>" size="42" />
<?php
}

function project_client(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$project_client = $custom["project_client"][0];
?>
<label for="project_client"><?php __('Project Client:', 'une_boutique') ?></label><br />
<input id="project_client" name="project_client" value="<?php echo $project_client; ?>" size="42" />
<?php
 }

function project_link(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$project_link = $custom["project_link"][0];
?>
<label for="project_link"><?php __('Project Link:', 'une_boutique') ?></label><br />
<input id="project_link" name="project_link" value="<?php echo $project_link; ?>" size="42" />
<?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_portfolio_details');
function save_portfolio_details() {
global $post;

update_post_meta($post->ID, "project_date", $_POST["project_date"]);
update_post_meta($post->ID, "project_client", $_POST["project_client"]);
update_post_meta($post->ID, "project_link", $_POST["project_link"]);
 }

add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "portfolios_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-portfolios_columns", "portfolios_edit_columns");

function portfolios_edit_columns($columns){
$columns = array(
    "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
    "title" => __('Item Title', 'une_boutique'),
    "year" => __('Project Date', 'une_boutique'),
    "Categories" => __('Categories', 'une_boutique'),
    "thumbnail" => __('Item Preview', 'une_boutique'),
);

return $columns;
 }

// GET FEATURED IMAGE for it's column
function ub_get_featured_image($post_ID) {
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_ID);
if ($post_thumbnail_id) {
    $post_thumbnail_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail');
    return $post_thumbnail_img[0];
}
}

function portfolios_custom_columns($column){
  global $post;

  switch ($column) {
case "year":
    $custom = get_post_custom();
    echo $custom["project_date"][0];
break;
case "Categories":
    echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'Categories', '', ', ','');
break;
case "thumbnail":
    global $post_ID;
    $post_featured_image = ub_get_featured_image($post_ID);
    if ($post_featured_image) {
        echo '<img src="' . $post_featured_image . '" width="50" height="50" />';
    }
break;
  }
}
```

Can any tell which part I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code in your shortcode function:

```
if( count($posts) ):
        echo '<ul id="portfolio-grid" class="portfolio-grid unstyled '.$post_columns.'-cols">';
        foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-largesrc="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo ub_featured_img_url('portfolio-fullsize'); } else { ?>http://placehold.it/600&text=<?php _e('No Thumbnails', 'une_boutique'); } ?>" data-title="<?php the_title() ?>" data-button="<?php _e('View Project', 'une_boutique'); ?>" data-description="<?php the_excerpt() ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else { ?>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320&text=<?php _e('No Thumbnails', 'une_boutique'); ?>" alt="no thumbnails">
                <?php } ?>
            <span class="item-title"><span class="arrow-shape-up"></span><?php the_title() ?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
        endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</ul>';
    endif;
```

Shortcodes should `return` their content.
Change this part into something like this:

```
if( count($posts) ):
  ob_start();

  echo '<ul id="portfolio-grid" class="portfolio-grid unstyled '.$post_columns.'-cols">';
        foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-largesrc="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo ub_featured_img_url('portfolio-fullsize'); } else { ?>http://placehold.it/600&text=<?php _e('No Thumbnails', 'une_boutique'); } ?>" data-title="<?php the_title() ?>" data-button="<?php _e('View Project', 'une_boutique'); ?>" data-description="<?php the_excerpt() ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else { ?>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320&text=<?php _e('No Thumbnails', 'une_boutique'); ?>" alt="no thumbnails">
                <?php } ?>
            <span class="item-title"><span class="arrow-shape-up"></span><?php the_title() ?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
        endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</ul>';

  return ob_get_clean();
endif;
```

Comment: WOW, Thanks, that did solve the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain me what `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean();` actually does? I tend to see them a lot lately.

Comment: Here are some phptutorial.info reference pages: [`ob_start`](http://phptutorial.info/?ob-start) and [`ob_get_clean`](http://phptutorial.info/?ob-get-clean).